# How do i do process syncronisation for the following code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, fork, semaphore

I have been trying to do some multithreading and process synchronisation. I am creating one parent and one child process using a fork.

How do I implement the parent-child synchronisation and what type of synchronisation i have to use?

I tried mutex, but ending in deadlocks.

```
// class1 threadfunction
void Class1::threadFunction()
{
    while(1)
    {
        std::cout<<"IN CLASS 1 FUNCTION\n\n";
        i++;
        sleep(2);
    }
}

//class 2 threadfunction
void Class2::threadFunction()
{
    while(1)
    {
        std::cout<<"IN CLASS 2 FUNCTION\n\n";
        j++;
        sleep(2);
    }
}

void Class1::create1()
{
    std::thread newThread (threadFunction);
    newThread.join();
}

void Class2::create2()
{
    std::thread newThread (threadFunction);
    newThread.join();
}

//main function

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"In Main\n\n";
    if(fork())
    {
        Class1 class1Object;
        class1Object.create1();
    }

    else
    {
        Class2 class2Object;
        class2Object.create2();
    }
}
```

I want the output to be sequential
ex:

```
IN CLASS 1 FUNCTION
IN CLASS 2 FUNCTION
IN CLASS 1 FUNCTION
IN CLASS 2 FUNCTION
IN CLASS 1 FUNCTION
IN CLASS 2 FUNCTION
IN CLASS 1 FUNCTION
IN CLASS 2 FUNCTION
```

.
.
.
.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to create a new process (using fork)? Wouldn't it be sufficient to just do _multithreading_ with _threads_?

Comment: you need have 2 events object. every thread signal event for another and wait for self event. if you want order

Comment: @LorenzZhao I have a while(1) loop inside the my function , how could i possibly create 2 threads if it gets stuck in the first ?

Comment: @ShreekarGowrishankar: take the .join() call out of your createN methods. To give you a working example, you should specify further what you want to achieve. (Just getting a sequential output does not require multithreading.) Is your goal to parallelize some long running stuff (the sleep(2) in your example code) and get the result of that stuff synchronized (alternating in your case)?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @LorenzZhao -- you should consider threading and synchronize with a mutex or semaphore.

On that note, if forking is the only option, you will need shared memory that both processes can access. This could be as simple as a file they both share, or a shared memory segment. In either case, you'll need to construct a mutex-like structure.

**EDIT**: As per @RbMm's note, if you're trying to get serialized synchronization, mutexes and semaphores are likely the wrong way to go. You could consider a flag variable such that a thread only operates when the flag is in a given state and sleeps otherwise; this would also mean that when a thread completes its operation, it needs to transition the flag variable to its subsequent state. This can also be accomplished in shared memory between separate processes.

Comment: mutex give exclusive access, but does not provide capture order.

Comment: Shared memory makes sense if i'm updating any values, but here they are just printing so no actual memory sharing requirement is there. And what are my options other than fork as thread function has a while(1) loop

Comment: So, the key thing to remember is that any synchronization you provide needs to be communicated between the separate lines of processing. Even in terms of UDP network processing, as long as the information isn't physically leaving the machine, it's just handled as a virtual file (i.e., shared memory). Threading vs Forking really doesn't have anything to do with the infinite-loop design; rather it's what you do within that loop that needs to change. Consider some sort of flag that each line of processing has to assess and either act when in one state and sleep in the other.